# Android Background Service with React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to run a background service in Android using HeadlessJS API from react native. I've used the official docs to do it:

MainTask file:

```
package com.test.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;

  import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
  import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
  import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;

  public class MyTaskService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {

    @Override
    protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

      if (extras != null) {
        return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
                "SomeTaskName",
                Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
                5000);
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```

I've also registered the task like this:

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => 'SomeTaskName')
```

and `SomeTaskName` is a function that looks like this:

```
export async function SomeTaskName (taskData) {
  alert('Esto es una tarea en background')
}
```

The way that I'm using to trigger this background task is using the `startService` method:

```
  startService(new Intent(this, MyTaskService.class));
```

I tried `startService` in different parts of the android code but I can't see any alert or warning logs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to figure this out too.  Here's what I've found so far.

If you don't put "extras" into to the Intent you pass to start the service then getTaskConfig() returns null.

```
protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

  if (extras != null) {
    return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
            "SomeTaskName",
            Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
            5000);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Either remove the check for extras != null, or add something like this before you call startService:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyTaskService.class);
myIntent.putExtras("isReady",true);
startService(myIntent);
```

Also, make sure you add the service to the manifest.

```
      <application>
        ....
        <service android:name=".MyTaskService" android:enabled="true" android:label="MyTaskService" />
      </application>
```

Comment: have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `getTaskConfig` method to support an intent that has no extras:

```
@Override
protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
  WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null;
  return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
            "SomeTaskName",
            data,
            5000);
}
```

Your Application class needs to implement ReactApplication and return an initialized ReactNativeHost, eg:

```
private final ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new MainReactPackage()
        );
    }
};

@Override
public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return reactNativeHost;
}
```

You also have to add the service to your manifest, as A. Rob mentioned.

**Edit**

Instead of implementing `ReactApplication` (see above) it seems like you could also override `protected ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost()` within the `HeadlessJsTaskService`.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I can see that you commented everywhere but not with good solutions that actually work

Comment: @bmm: My answer did work at the time of writing, but I can't provide an update, because I currently do not use React Native anymore. I hope you could figure it out.